# get selected item id from datagrid filled by database WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, casting, selecteditem, selectedvalue

My question was how to get the item or value of a selecteditem out of my datagrid that gets filled by a obc of my view. From te result that i get it seems i need to cast it but all the casts i found from google and here are not working.

Anyone got some tips or solution?

```
public partial class req: Page
    {

        DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        public requests()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
          //get from Database View  
           var query = from r in dc.requestViews select r;

            this.gridRequest.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<requestView>(query);
            this.gridRequest.ColumnWidth = 122.7;
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (gridRequest.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select a Order!");
            }
            else
            {

               var qres = (from r in dc.orders where r.id.Equals(gridRequest.SelectedValue) select r).FirstOrDefault();
               qres.order_status_id = 3;
               dc.SubmitChanges();

                MessageBox.Show("Request Accepted");
                this.NavigationService.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `this.dgaanvraag.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<aanvraagView>(query);` - EPIC. You should code in english exclusively, seriously.

Comment: Changed to english srry x|